# What packages does beamer load automatically?

Tags: beamer, packages

I just learned that `beamer` loads `amsmath` and `graphicx` packages automatically, what other packages does it load?

Comment: Related [Create list of all external files used by master LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24542/15717)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just add `\listfiles` to the preamble, then you will get a list in your log file:
Note, `beamer` loads packages which then load other packages.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The output will look like, depending on the `beamer` and `packages` versions:

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2013/01/04 3.26 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revi
sion e81e0c94bcc6)
beamerbasercs.sty    2013/01/04 (rcs-revision 9a97a4eee358)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2012/04/15 (rcs-revision cc6557182d97)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2010/04/27 (rcs-revision 982469101dd6)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2012/09/19  (rcs-revision 733629cd0c6c)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2012/02/24  (rcs-revision 2ff5461be705)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2012/11/11  (rcs-revision 6afbc49b1109)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/01/04  (rcs-revision 54309ceef997)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2012/12/26  (rcs-revision 1443917db2cf)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2012/08/30  (rcs-revision dfdb135076b3)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2012/09/13  (rcs-revision dcd846607320)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision d1a9b48be06d)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2012/10/02  (rcs-revision 5ed0f4010e8a)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2012/11/13  (rcs-revision ddfba79dac19)
enumerate.sty    1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2012/04/03  (rcs-revision 42a0f21a412d)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict
 ***********
```

Comment: What if a package loads another one that loads another .....:P

Comment: @percusse Good thought! I guess the OP would like to know the end result, including the packages `beamer` loads implicitly, because they will be there.

Comment: Thanks! Strange they are not sorted in alphabetic order.

Comment: @percusse [How to design a command inquiring internally required packages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119469)

Comment: @LWZ The list is in order of loading